# Minimal number of generators of satellite knot groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory

In light of [Knot groups with big number of generators](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/397498/knot-groups-with-big-number-of-generators), I was wondering...

> **Question 1** What is the minimal number of generators of the fundamental group of a [satellite knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_knot)?

Another more specific question

> **Question 2**  If we take a twisted Whitehead double of a nontrivial knot, what is the minimal number of generators of the resulting knot group?

Comment: @MarkSapir All knots have abelianized fundamental group isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$, so you won't get any nontrivial bounds the way you suggest. The linked thread discusses some nontrivial results for knot groups.

Comment: In general there aren’t good results known for ranks of amalgams. A very basic question might be: must the rank of a non-trivial satellite knot be at least 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Knot groups of satellite knots can have rank 2, and only the trivial knot can have rank 1, so 2 is the minimal possible number of generators.

The knot group of any tunnel number one knot has a presentation with 2 generators and 1 relator. [Morimoto and Sakuma](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01446565) classified all satellite knots which have tunnel number one. In their notation (see section 1.7 of their article), I believe that the tunnel number one knot $K(8,3;p,q)$ will be some Whitehead double of the $(p,q)$-torus knot. Thus there exist Whitehead doubles of torus knots whose knot groups have rank 2.