# Minimal generators of the fundamental groups of Whitehead doubled knot

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator\rank{rank}$My question involves a special kind of [satellite knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_knot) named (Whitehead) doubled knot. The definition is quoted from [Klassen's paper](https://eudml.org/doc/141701) but the construction is pretty standard. For those who are familiar with the notion, please feel free to skip to the question part.

[image]
[image]
My question is related to the recent posts [Knot groups with big number of generators](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/397498/knot-groups-with-big-number-of-generators) and [Minimal number of generators of satellite knot groups](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/397710/minimal-number-of-generators-of-satellite-knot-groups)

> **Question** Let $K$ be a nontrivial knot and $K_n$ be the $n$-twisted double of $K$. Is $\rank(\pi_1(S^3 - K_n)) \geq \rank(\pi_1(S^3 - K))$, for any $n$?

Here the rank of a group G is the smallest cardinality of a generating set for G.